# Why ssrs shows different number of rows than SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have SP with with Parameter @IsMatch which checks if

```
ChildPolicyNumberRater <> ChildPolicyNumberIMS
```

and also parameter @ChildPolicyNumber that allows user to use WildCard parameter.

[image]

If I ran  the SP in SSMS with parameter `'No Match'` it gives me right data `ChildPolicyNumberRater NULLS` and also the ones that dont match `ChildPolicyNumberIMS`:

[image]

But then If I ran it in SSRS the it displays only records where `ChildPolicyNumber NULLS`.

I am sure it something in my `WHERE` clause that makes SSRS display data different than SSMS. But I cannot understand why!

[image]

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcedure 
            @DateFrom datetime = '2017-01-30'
            @DateTo datetime = '2017-03-05'
            @lineGuid  varchar(8000) = NULL, 
            @IsMatch varchar(50),
            @ChildPolicyNumber varchar(50)

    AS
    DECLARE @TempData
    INSERT INTO @TempData
    SELECT ...
    FROM...
    WHERE 

    SELECT 
            ChildPolicyNumberIMS
            ,ChildPolicyNumberRater
            ,case when ChildPolicyNumberRater <> ChildPolicyNumberIMS or  ChildPolicyNumberRater is null then 1 else 0 end as status
            ,MAX([InvoiceDate]) as InvoiceDate
            ,[CompanyGUID]
    WHERE 
              (

            ChildPolicyNumberRater like '%'+ @ChildPolicyNumber +'%'
            or ChildPolicyNumberRater is null
            or @ChildPolicyNumber   is null
            )
        and (
                    (@IsMatch = 'No Match'
                        and ChildPolicyNumberRater<>ChildPolicyNumberIMS or ChildPolicyNumberRater is null)

                or(@IsMatch = 'Match' and ChildPolicyNumberRater=ChildPolicyNumberIMS)

            )
```

Comment: `(@IsMatch = 'No Match'
                        and ChildPolicyNumberRater<>ChildPolicyNumberIMS or ChildPolicyNumberRater is null)` looks like a curious mix of `and` and `or`. Is `( ( @IsMatch = 'No Match'
                        and ChildPolicyNumberRater<>ChildPolicyNumberIMS ) or ChildPolicyNumberRater is null)` what you want? That is what you'll get due to operator precendence.

Comment: Oh!!!  I am condused.   I want if it `match`, then only matching records without `nulls`, but if  `no match` - then return `nulls` and also no matching records (in `ChildPolicyNumberRater` column)

Comment: I think you need only - (@ChildPolicyNumber IS NULL OR ChildPolicyNumberRater LIKE '%'+@ChildPolicyNumber+'%')

Comment: Then how about `Match` `No Match` parameter?

Comment: In the SSRS screenshot the dropdown says "Not Match" rather than "No Match".  Are you sure you are sending No Match?

Comment: OMG!!!  @Alex you made my day. That exactly was the cause of wrong behavior.  How important is id to be detail oriented!!!
Please, post it as an answer and I'll accept it. 
Thank you very very very very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SSRS screenshot the dropdown says "Not Match" rather than "No Match". Are you sure you are sending No Match?